# input xml file to php with multiple elements in a element?

Tags: php, xml, input

Hello i am having much trouble inputting the following XML because of the multiple "authors" .. it works when i try with 1 but with multiple it fails. does anyone know how i can do the multiple author input?  below is my an example of the xml and code

```
<pub>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <title>A Sampling Based Approach to Facial Feature Extraction</title>
    <year>2005</year>
    <booktitle>AutoID</booktitle>
    <pages>51-56</pages>
    <authors>
        <author>john johnson</author>
        <author>billy bob</author>
    </authors>
</pub>
```

my code:

```
<?php

$pubs = new SimpleXMLElement('p.xml', null, true);

echo <<<EOF
<table>
    <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>year</th>
            <th>booktitle</th>
            <th>pages</th>
            <th>authors</th>
    </tr>

EOF;
foreach($pubs as $pub)
{
    echo <<<EOF
    <tr>
            <td>{$pub->ID}</td>
            <td>{$pub->title}</td>
            <td>{$pub->year}</td>
            <td>{$pub->booktitle}</td>
            <td>{$pub->pages}</td>
            <td>{$pub->authors}</td>
    </tr>


EOF;
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authors are a several nodes, so you have to use a second loop. Additionally if you output values in HTML/XML, you need to escape them. `htmlspecialchars()` does a good enough job for that.

You're transforming XML into HTML here. XSLT would be a better tool for that. It is supported by the XSL extension in PHP.

In PHP you can use Xpath to extract data from XML:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('p.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

echo <<<EOF
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>year</th>
    <th>booktitle</th>
    <th>pages</th>
    <th>authors</th>
  </tr>
EOF;

$pubs = $xpath->evaluate('//pub');
foreach($pubs as $pub) {
  echo '<tr>', "\n";
  echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(./ID)', $pub)), '</td>', "\n";
  echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(./title)', $pub)), '</td>', "\n";
  echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(./year)', $pub)), '</td>', "\n";
  echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(./booktitle)', $pub)), '</td>', "\n";
  echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(./pages)', $pub)), '</td>', "\n";

  // fetch all the authors into an array
  $authors = array();
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('./authors/author', $pub) as $author) {
    $authors[] = $author->nodeValue;
  }
  echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars(implode(', ', $authors)).'</td>', "\n";
  echo '</tr>', "\n";
}
echo '</table>';
```

The example uses DOMXpath::evaluate() because it allows to query string directly from the DOM. `$xpath->evaluate('string(./ID)', $pub)` returns the text content inside the ID child of the context node $pub, or an empty string if here is no child element ID.

Comment: would this be a php file if i create it in VI in linus?

Comment: It is PHP source, to be placed after a `<?php `.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way, i think, is to convert it to json string than back to array and you will see that is an array so you will need another *foreach*

```
$pubs = new SimpleXMLElement('p.xml', null, true);    
$jsonString = json_encode($pubs);
$assocArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($assocArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Sorry. I give you wrong informations, because if you tried this code you will get different result if you have more than 1 '' tags and if you have only 1.

So i have another solution:

```
<?php
$pubs = new SimpleXMLElement('test.xml', null, true);

echo <<<EOF
<table>
    <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>year</th>
            <th>booktitle</th>
            <th>pages</th>
            <th>authors</th>
    </tr>

EOF;

$pubsXpath = $pubs->xpath('//pub');
/** @var SimpleXMLElement $pub */
foreach ($pubsXpath as $pub) {
    $authorsSxml = $pub->xpath('authors/author');
    $authors = join(', ', $authorsSxml);
    echo <<<EOF
    <tr>
            <td>{$pub->ID}</td>
            <td>{$pub->title}</td>
            <td>{$pub->year}</td>
            <td>{$pub->booktitle}</td>
            <td>{$pub->pages}</td>
            <td>{$authors}</td>
    </tr>
EOF;
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```